# how to open file chooser in android using gluon moblie?

Tags: java, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports, gluon-desktop

how to open file chooser in android using gluon mobile?

how to save an image usng gluon mobile?

I reffer many web sites but there was no answer.

Comment: With the [`PictureService`](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PicturesService.html), you can access the gallery, with the [`StorageService`](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/StorageService.html) you can save files. For a more concrete answer, edit your question and add more details of what you have already done and does not work for you.

Comment: I'm not sure how AdView relates to this current question. If there is an error, edit the question and post what you have done so far, what are you trying to do and what is failing (including logcat errors).

Comment: Again, that's another question that has nothing to do with this one.

Comment: answer to this question .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783927/gluon-adview-error-in-android-java-packages                                                                                 this question is based on adview